# select rows in data frame with their key frequency greater than threshold

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame A with the first column as the first column as the numeric key.  An example will be like this

```
key     feature_1       feature_2
101      1.1              1.2
102      1.3              1.2
101      1.2              1.3
.............................
```

Now I want to select the rows with the first column value (key) appear more than 5 times for each distinct key, what should be the efficient command for large size A?

I think it should be something like this

```
subset(A, key %in% c(.... # please fill in here) ) ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options to consider, with some sample data to test it out for efficiency. Change the threshold (here I've used "6") to whatever you actually want.

```
## Sample data
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(key = sample(10, 100, TRUE),
                   feature1 = runif(100), feature2 = runif(100))
```

#### Base R: `ave`

```
Len <- with(mydf, ave(key, key, FUN = length))
mydf[Len > 6, ]
```

#### data.table: `.N`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, Len := .N, by = key]
DT[Len > 6]
```

#### dplyr: `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %.%
  group_by(key) %.%
  mutate(Len = n()) %.%
  filter(Len > 6)
```

Comment: In a few quick tests, `ave` works out to be faster for up to 3500 rows or so, but `data.table` quickly takes over after that.